# How to securely download files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

The below method is used to download a YAML file, based on user param/selection.

This is not secure for sure, as I can download other YAML files in the hierarchy.

```
def download

    language_code = params[:code]
    send_file(
        "#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{language_code}.yml",
        filename: "#{language_code}.yml",
        type: "application/yml"
    )

end
```

I can't have a hold on `params[:code]` which is dynamic in nature.

How do I secure the `download` method here, which is vulnerable?

Comment: what's an instance that you're trying to protect against?

Comment: @Anthony `database.yml` file can be pulled.

Comment: Can you make a `safe_list` or a `unsafe_list` array holding language_code's you're ok with users downloading?

Comment: Since this `file access` vulnerability is in a function dealing with downloading a very specific type of files, checking it against a list of permitted values before downloading would make it a totally safe operation.

Comment: As I said `language_codes` are not pre-set, else it would have been straight forward shot.

Comment: If you really can't whitelist, I'm not sure you can really make this 100% secure. I would create both a blacklist and remove any `../`s from `params[:code]`.

Comment: I'd store the information *and* the YAML in a database. Then you can easily control what is sent and what is visible by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #1 option, as the comments have implied is to completely dis-allow the user from interacting with
the `language_code` string. There are a number of suggested options for that in the comments: restricted
list, database implementation, etc.

Another option (although given your constraints this may not be valid) is to do a length check: `language_code.length <= 4`. This assumes your language code doesn't exceed 4 characters as per [wikipedia's list of language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

**As a last resort** you can also sanitize the user input and clean it up so that the file path cannot be
manipulated. [I've written a post about file sanitization functions here](http://gavinmiller.io/2016/creating-a-secure-sanitization-function/). You have two options:

- whitelist and only accept a small subset of characters: `A-Z, a-z, 0-9`
- blacklist and eliminiate dangerous characters: `/ \ ? % * : | " < > . (and space)`

In your case (I'm assuming you have full control of `config/locals`) I'd whitelist. A whitelist function is
easy to create:

```
def sanitize(file_name)
  # Remove any character that aren't 0-9, A-Z, or a-z
  filename.gsub(/[^0-9A-Z]/i, '_')
end
```

Not knowing how your language files are implemented, you may need to use a character other than underscore `_`
for replacement.

For extra precaution, you can also pre-check the directory to see if the file exists, which would prevent a
path traversal attack. Something like this:

```
def valid_path?(filename)
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/config/locales/*"].include?("#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{filename}")
end
```

The benefit here is that you're explicitly stating that the file must exist in the `config/locales` directory
before you serve it. If an attacker tries a directory traversal attack, this function is going to return false.